# Trouble assigning keyword argument values to ivars in ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, rspec, keyword-argument

I'm attempting to write a constructor for a class in ruby 2.1.5 using keyword arguments with default values, however assignment to instance variables does not seem to be working:

```
class Base
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize name: "void",
                 contents: []

    @name          = name
    @contents      = contents
  end
end
```

In my rspec test:

```
it 'should take optional param name' do
  subject { Base.new(name: "fnordland") }
  expect(subject.name).to eq "fnordland"
end
```

fails like so:

```
2) Base initialize should take optional param location_name
 Failure/Error: expect(subject.name).to eq "fnordland"

   expected: "fnordland"
        got: "void"

   (compared using ==)
```

The initializer works as expected in IRB, but the test fails. 
I know in my bones that this is likely something very small and utterly idiotic but I'm flummoxed - examples of keyword argument assignment to ivars in ruby 2.1 seem to indicate that this should work.

Comment: Your code works as it should when I run it.

Comment: It seems to work in irb, so I reckon the issue is likely my test, somehow.

Comment: `subject` should go [outside your `it` block](http://betterspecs.org/#subject).

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with the ordering of your test case. With the RSpec DSL, it can sometimes get a bit confusing what can go where. You'd need to do one of either:

```
it 'should take optional param name' do
  base = Base.new(name: "fnordland")
  expect(base.name).to eq "fnordland"
end
```

or:

```
subject { Base.new(name: "fnordland") }
it { expect(subject.name).to eq "fnordland" }
```